# Does the TimeActivity query in the QBO v3 API work?

Tags: intuit-partner-platform

I want to love the v3 API. Unfortunately, when making the seemingly simple call:

```
service.executeQuery("select * from TimeActivity");
```

I get the crushing reply of:

```
<Error code="6002">
<Message>message=Timeout occurred while proxying request; errorCode=006002; statusCode=504</Message>
</Error>
```

What kind of problem could cause this?

Comment: Please mention if you are having an Essential subscription or Plus QBO subscription. Time tracking is not supported by Essential subscription

Comment: Yes, I have time tracking. As indicated in a comment below, my application works beautifully with the v2 API.

Answer (score 0):

Typically a 504 error code [indicates there is a dependency timeout](http://www.checkupdown.com/status/E504.html). It is clear that the server you are contacting is responsive, as you are receiving the response.

This kind of error is common if there is any kind of fault in the back end of the server or some service they rely on has gone down. You may want to contact the system administrator or responsible support team to ask about this, as it's likely affecting anyone accessing the same service as you.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like something is wrong with my account. All TimeActivity queries fail in the API explorer. To Intuit support I go!

Comment: Were you using a trial account ?
Please check if you are getting any authentication error (401).
you can post the error msg here.

Thanks

Comment: No trial. I am using a real god-fearing account. The v2 API works like a charm, but v3 blows up on the server side. The error is posted in my original above.